# When hook_field_load and hook_field_formatter_view are called?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I have implemented the `hook_field_load()` and `hook_field_formatter_view()` function to replace some characters in a specific field's value. But they don't seem to be called at all.
I wrote some command like `exit()` and `print_r($field)` in the hooks but nothing happens.

When this hooks are called? (and is this the correct way to do alter field values for view?)

Answer (score 5):

`hook_field_load()` and `hook_field_formatter_view()` aren't hooks really. They rather are callbacks which only can be used from a module implementing the field in question by itself. The documentation at api.drupal.org for both hooks is not very clear in that by stating nothing or just a vague:

> Define custom load behavior for this module's field types.

When grepping through the Drupal 7 code you never see this so called hooks invoked by `module_invoke_all()` which is a clear sign for that functions are not handled like hooks.

`hook_field_attach_load()` may be used instead of `hook_field_load()` which is a real hook.

See also the discussion at http://drupal.org/node/702586 for that matter.